# Shopify Dawn Theme - Add Icons in place of Bullet points in multicolumn layout

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template, shopify-storefront-api

Customizing Dawn Theme and in multicolumn I have added bullet text but am not able to change icons before the text. Font Awesome Icons are not visible. I have added CDN of font awesome.

I am looking for a similar format as icons text (Need one column)only.

I have added this code but not showing any icons.

```
<div class="multicolumn-card__info">
  {%- if block.settings.title != blank -%}
    <h3 class="inline-richtext">{{ block.settings.title }}</h3>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if block.settings.text != blank -%}
    <div class="rte">
      {{ block.settings.text | replace: '<ul>', '<ul class="fa-ul">' | replace: '<li>', '<li><i class="fa-li fas fa-check"></i>' }}
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if block.settings.link_label != blank -%}
    <a
      class="link animate-arrow"
      {% if block.settings.link == blank %}
        role="link" aria-disabled="true"
      {% else %}
        href="{{ block.settings.link }}"
      {% endif %}
    >
      {{- block.settings.link_label | escape -}}
      <span class="icon-wrap">&nbsp;{% render 'icon-arrow' %}</span>
    </a>
  {%- endif -%}
</div>
```

[image]

Appreciate all the help.